# Material Design Lite Layout similar to Google Support webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

Is there an existing Material Design Lite template that provides a rendering similar to Google Developer Console Help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd do best to learn the Materials Grid, and check out some of the individual components. Everything else will flow from there.

The example you have should work fine. Just adjust the columns to allow for your sidebar. See [Layouts](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section)

The primary content can be housed in a card, which will provide all the spacing and margin you are looking for, as well as have a configurable shadow (e.g **mdl-shadow--2dp**) See [Cards](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section)

You can compare against the [Text-Heavy Webpage Template](https://getmdl.io/templates/text-only/index.html) for how to nest elements within cards.

Comment: Thank you Gopherkhan. However, I cannot figure out how to get a background ribbon that fills half of the screen and expands with menu content. Neither how to get expandable Step actions inside page content. Any idea?

Comment: It really boils down to just flexbox and javascript. You can take a look at the components here [https://getmdl.io/components/index.htm], but you will probably have to add the show/hide logic yourself.

Comment: Also, take the time to do this flexbox tutorial. http://flexboxfroggy.com/  Then most of what you're looking to do will be simple.